# During a Helm upgrade is there a way to access the version I am upgrading from

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Example: Current version is 1.2.3 and I execute a helm upgrade to version 1.2.4, during the upgrade in the statefulset is there a way to access the "from" version e.g. 1.2.3

Comment: What do you mean by "access" and "version"?  (HTTP call to an existing pod; pass a string as a parameter to a job script; ...?)  Can you give an example of the specific thing you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for delay, yes an example, I am on 1.2.3, I execute helm upgrade to 1.2.4, in my stateful set I have a check for 
{{- if .Release.IsUpgrade }}
The next line should check if the version I am upgrading from is less than 1.2.4 then don't execute that block

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can access the "from" version during the upgrade, but you can get it before applying the upgrade with [`helm list`](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_list/) command

```
helm list --filter 'your-release' -n your-namespace -o json | jq '.[0]'
{
  "name": "your-release",
  "namespace": "your-namespace",
  "revision": "549",
  "updated": "2020-07-31 14:54:44.168919115 +0000 UTC",
  "status": "failed",
  "chart": "your-chart-0.1.0",
  "app_version": "0.2.1"
}
```

As stated in [helm docs](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#charts-and-versioning)

> Packages in repositories are identified by name plus version.

You can cut the version from returned `chart` key

```
PREVIOUS_VERSION=$(helm list --filter 'your-release' -n your-namespace -o json | jq '.[0].chart' | grep -Po '(?<=your-chart-)[^;]+' | sed 's/.$//')
echo $PREVIOUS_VERSION
0.1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but this can only be checked at upgrade, as an example, I am on 1.2.3, I execute helm upgrade to 1.2.4, in my stateful set I have a check for {{- if .Release.IsUpgrade }} The next line should check if the version I am upgrading from is less than 1.2.4 then don't execute that block

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in functionality that I know of and there is no easy way to access the previous version, but there might be a workaround.

You can use the method mentioned by *edbighead* to get the previous version and pass it with `--set` like following:

```
helm upgrade --set previousVersion=$PREVIOUS_VERSION
```

and then use this conditional statement in the chart:

```
{{- $var := semver .Values.previousVersion | (semver "1.2.4" ).Compare }}
{{- if ne $var 1 }}
  ...
{{- end }}
```

The if statement will be true only if `previousVersion` is greater or equal to 1.2.4.

Here is more about [semantic version function (semver) in helm](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#semantic-version-functions).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the requirements= is to do this completely in logic with no new values/sets as the person doing an upgrade would not be altering their upgrade command. As you mentioned there is no built in functionality I will have to look for an alternative workaround.