# Helm get major version of current release

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Can I get the helm chart version currently installed from within the helm templating engine? I would like to add a configmap (containing a db migration script) depending on wether or it upgraded from version 1.0.0 to 2.1.0 or from 2.0.0 to 2.1.0 for example.

Or are there any other techniques to accomplish the same?

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Yes, you have chart version - {{ .Chart.Version }} - https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/

Comment: This is discussed further in [During a Helm upgrade is there a way to access the version I am upgrading from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63191212/during-a-helm-upgrade-is-there-a-way-to-access-the-version-i-am-upgrading-from).  You can get the current version, and you can know whether it is a first-time install, but you can't access the release metadata from the previous installation.

Comment: (Most database migration systems I have experience with record migration data in the database itself, and know to skip over a migration that's already been run; I would include the migration script in the image, and possibly run migrations in a separate pre-upgrade hook job unconditionally.)